# Google maps on Galaxy S4 doesn't search nearby

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, maps

Using the Maps up on a Galaxy S4, when I search for a store name (like "starbucks"), it should show me the nearest results, but instead it shows me results in other cities (like the Starbucks in Seattle, or Home Depot in Atlanta).

The Maps app shows my correct current location, so the GPS etc is working and the app knows where I'm at.. what else could be going wrong?